# AWSMobileHubHelper sign-in Google can't work via cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

I have an iOS app use aws sdk when integrate with google sign in use `AWSMobileHubHelper` .

Everything is fine, but when call `AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance().login()` in `LoginViewController`

it throw a error:

`-[GIDSignIn setAllowsSignInWithBrowser:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14cd97540`

I've install sdk from pod:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PhotoMap' do
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 2.0'
   pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 2.0'
   pod 'AWSS3'
   pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2'
   pod 'AWSCognito'
   pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider'
   pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
   pod 'AWSLambda'
   pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.9'
   pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.9'
   pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.9'
   pod 'GoogleSignIn'
end
```

Here is my project after pod install:

[image]

I've add `-force_load` to `Other linker flats`:

[image]

And I have add a `PhotoMap-Bridging-Header.h`:

```
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a duplicate of this issue reported in the AWS forums:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236455&tstart=0

Here's the response to that issue...

Our recommendation is to use the frameworks which are included in the AWS Mobile Hub quickstart sample app project download, including the related AWS, Facebook, and Google SDK frameworks. This will help you avoid any compatibility issues between SDK versions, which may result if you try pulling SDKs in via CocoaPods or some other method.

Also, please make sure the -ObjC flag is removed from your project settings, since this will attempt to force-load frameworks which your project may not require. You should however use the force_load setting for the Google frameworks, as described in the READ_ME/index.html file in your quickstart app project download (in the section under "Set up the compiler settings for GoogleSignIn SDK").